# npm install keeps looping forever

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I am having an issue when running npm install for a project I am working on.

It seems that it constantly re-runs the npm install command (until manually killed). The weird thing is, after the first npm install all the dependencies are installed and work as normal. This is becoming an issue when trying to use some CI tools to auto build my code.

I have tested this under the following conditions;

- Windows OS
- Linux OS
- Various Node/NPM versions (6.x and 8.x branch)
- With a simple package.json of only a single dependency.
- Clearing npm cache

Versions of node/npm currently using;

- Node: v6.11.5
- NPM: 3.10.10

Simple package.json that shows the issue:

```
{
  "name": "tool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Jeff",
  "description": "A starter project",
  "repository": {},
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "contributors": [],
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "npm install",
    "serve-dev": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "serve-prod": "ng serve --prod --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build-dev": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod"
  }
}
```

NPM Install Logs:

```
npm -dd install
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', '-dd', 'install' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.5
npm verb mapToRegistry no registry URL found in name for scope @angular
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 3:41:11 PM
npm verb request id 10054e4c6c4b8242
npm verb etag W/"59f29d79-234ca"
npm verb lastModified Fri, 27 Oct 2017 02:44:09 GMT
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon
npm verb headers { date: 'Fri, 27 Oct 2017 23:41:13 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"59f29d79-234ca"',
npm verb headers   age: '0',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-mdw17339-MDW',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1509147674.967823,VS0,VE358',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon from cache
npm verb get saving @angular/common to /home/jeff/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/_40angular_252fcommon/.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec @angular/common@4.4.6
npm verb addNamed "4.4.6" is a plain semver version for @angular/common
npm verb mapToRegistry no registry URL found in name for scope @angular
npm verb addNameVersion registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon not in flight; fetching
npm verb get https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon not expired, no request
npm verb afterAdd /home/jeff/.npm/@angular/common/4.4.6/package/package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd /home/jeff/.npm/@angular/common/4.4.6/package/package.json written
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 3:41:14 PM
npm verb etag W/"59dd9f6d-4c68"
npm verb lastModified Wed, 11 Oct 2017 04:34:53 GMT
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib
npm verb headers { date: 'Fri, 27 Oct 2017 23:41:15 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"59dd9f6d-4c68"',
npm verb headers   age: '172',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-mdw17339-MDW',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1509147675.077783,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib from cache
npm verb get saving tslib to /home/jeff/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/tslib/.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec tslib@^1.7.1
npm verb addNamed ">=1.7.1 <2.0.0" is a valid semver range for tslib
npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib not in flight; fetching
npm verb get https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib not expired, no request
npm verb addNamed "1.8.0" is a plain semver version for tslib
npm verb afterAdd /home/jeff/.npm/tslib/1.8.0/package/package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd /home/jeff/.npm/tslib/1.8.0/package/package.json written
npm info lifecycle xsltool@1.0.0~preinstall: xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /home/jeff/.npm/_locks/staging-950641377131bc6f.lock for /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging
npm verb unbuild node_modules/.staging/@angular/common-b1bc935a
npm verb unbuild node_modules/.staging/tslib-34a2ed6e
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/@angular/common-b1bc935a
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/tslib-34a2ed6e
npm verb tar unpack /home/jeff/.npm/@angular/common/4.4.6/package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/@angular/common-b1bc935a
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/@angular/common-b1bc935a
npm verb tar unpack /home/jeff/.npm/tslib/1.8.0/package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/tslib-34a2ed6e
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/tslib-34a2ed6e
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/tslib-34a2ed6e/node_modules
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging/@angular/common-b1bc935a/node_modules
npm info lifecycle tslib@1.8.0~preinstall: tslib@1.8.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/common@4.4.6~preinstall: @angular/common@4.4.6
npm info linkStuff tslib@1.8.0
npm verb linkBins tslib@1.8.0
npm verb linkMans tslib@1.8.0
npm info linkStuff @angular/common@4.4.6
npm verb linkBins @angular/common@4.4.6
npm verb linkMans @angular/common@4.4.6
npm info lifecycle tslib@1.8.0~install: tslib@1.8.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/common@4.4.6~install: @angular/common@4.4.6
npm info lifecycle tslib@1.8.0~postinstall: tslib@1.8.0
npm info lifecycle @angular/common@4.4.6~postinstall: @angular/common@4.4.6
npm verb unlock done using /home/jeff/.npm/_locks/staging-950641377131bc6f.lock for /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging
npm info linkStuff xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb linkBins xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb linkMans xsltool@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle xsltool@1.0.0~install: xsltool@1.0.0

> xsltool@1.0.0 install /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp
> npm install

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.5
npm info lifecycle xsltool@1.0.0~preinstall: xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /home/jeff/.npm/_locks/staging-950641377131bc6f.lock for /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging
npm verb unlock done using /home/jeff/.npm/_locks/staging-950641377131bc6f.lock for /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging
npm info linkStuff xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb linkBins xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb linkMans xsltool@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle xsltool@1.0.0~install: xsltool@1.0.0

> xsltool@1.0.0 install /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp
> npm install

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.5
npm info lifecycle xsltool@1.0.0~preinstall: xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb correctMkdir /home/jeff/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /home/jeff/.npm/_locks/staging-950641377131bc6f.lock for /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging
npm verb unlock done using /home/jeff/.npm/_locks/staging-950641377131bc6f.lock for /mnt/c/work/personal/LiveXSLTransformUI/tmp/node_modules/.staging
npm info linkStuff xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb linkBins xsltool@1.0.0
npm verb linkMans xsltool@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle xsltool@1.0.0~install: xsltool@1.0.0
```

Comment: npm 5.5.1 is out now. Maybe it is time for an upgrade(?).

Comment: I have tried 5.5.1, and the same issue persists. The reason for using the version I am is that it comes with the version of node.js that I installed.

Comment: The it after removing the `install` line from the scripts section of the package.json.

Comment: Omg your a genuis, I cant believe I never thought of that! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 15):

As R. Richards pointed out correctly. Removing the "install" script line fixed it. Seems to get in some permanent loop if that is in your pacakge.json!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today myself, wanted to provide a variant on the solution if someone else runs into this.

**TL;DR;** since `install` is a keyword, the only thing you need to do is change the script name to something different like `"install:main": "npm install"`. But if thats all it is, I would just get rid of the script itself.

---

On my project, we are still stuck with running `--legacy-peer-deps` when doing an `npm install`. So I got tired of forgetting to put it in there when I needed to do a fresh install. Thats when I ran into the same problem at the OP. So I added:

```
"install": "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
```

This resulted in the infinite loop again, which understandably happened now that I know about it, I used a keyword and got an abnormal result.

But I still didn't want to go back to doing it the old way, and I am currently working on setting up an install command that will have more flags or less flags depending on what I'm doing (won't go into that here as its annoyingly complicated).

So what I've settled on is:

```
"install:legadcy-peer-deps": "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
```

Which got me back to working.